# How to set proxy with a config file provided in freebsd

Tags: networking, freebsd, proxy

I'm currently trying to update and install packages and other things on a FreeBSD server, but I’m blocked by my proxy. I'm in an university, and there are a few proxies before to go on the internet.

To allow us ty bypass the proxy on our main PC (Debian 7) we need to enter the path of a config file in the networks settings (auto mode in proxy menu)
But I can't manage to do this to my FreeBSD server.

What can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Most command line tools will respect an environment variable to configure a proxy, i.e. `export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.local:8888`